# axios SSL error with Node 12 : SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol

Tags: node.js, ssl, axios

I’m running into an issue with `axios` and Node 12. As I’m not sure this error is only related to `axios`, I followed the advice to ask on SO rather than opening a bug on axios’ GitHub.

Here is the code I’m trying to run :

```js
const axios = require('axios')

axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: 'https://www.colisprive.com/moncolis/pages/detailColis.aspx?numColis=12345',
  responseType: 'text'
}).then((response) => {
  console.log(response)
})
```

This code fails on Node 12 with following error :

```
Error: write EPROTO 140121214769024:error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/statem/statem_lib.c:1929:

    at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:87:16)
```

**Same code ran against Node 11 doesn’t throw any error.**

When I `curl -v` I got this :

```
*   Trying 91.208.224.32:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.colisprive.com (91.208.224.32) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: serialNumber=391029345; jurisdictionC=FR; businessCategory=Private Organization; C=FR; postalCode=13290; ST=Bouches-du-Rh�ne; L=AIX EN PROVENCE; street=1330 AV J R G GAUTIER DE LA LAUZIERE; street=ZI MILLES EUROPARC PICHAURY; O=COLIS PRIVE SAS; OU=0002 391029345; CN=www.colisprive.com
*  start date: Sep  3 00:00:00 2018 GMT
*  expire date: Sep  2 23:59:59 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "www.colisprive.com" matched cert's "www.colisprive.com"
*  issuer: C=GB; ST=Greater Manchester; L=Salford; O=COMODO CA Limited; CN=COMODO RSA Extended Validation Secure Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /moncolis/pages/detailColis.aspx?numColis=12345 HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.colisprive.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.65.3
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Location: /moncolis/Default.aspx?numColis=12345&cp=
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
< Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=eln3cq143d35lfj5tpqkkwcg; path=/; HttpOnly
< X-Powered-By: Colis Priv�
< Date: Fri, 24 Jan 2020 13:48:35 GMT
< Content-Length: 162
< 
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/moncolis/Default.aspx?numColis=12345&amp;cp=">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
* Connection #0 to host www.colisprive.com left intact
```

As you can see, it gives a `302 Found` with a `Location` header pointing to another endpoint. I agree it should answer a `301 Moved` to indicate document has moved, but this is not the case and it is handled as expected by `axios` on Node 11 (fetching endpoint under `Location` header).

I saw that Node 12 now includes TLS 1.3 as default, so this could be related to that…

Also, there is an unknown character in `X-Powered-By` header.

I tried to :

- reproduce this issue with an `express` server always replying `302 Found` with same headers : works as expected
- fetch another `.aspx` web page with `axios` : works as expected

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem is not just with `axios` but with `got` as well.

Node.js 12's default TLS settings are stricter now. The site doesn't handle TLS v1.2. Node 12 by default need 1.2.

You can change this via a command line flag (--tls-min-v1.0) when running your app.

something like this

```
node --tls-min-v1.0 app.js
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now as expected with Node 12 ! But I’d like to understand why `curl` is working and displaying TLS handshakes with 1.2 and 1.3 ?